# C# wpf - Replace edited datagrid cell value with the existing one

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to update row to database if the `ClientSave` button is clicked. But my problem is that I access values through a datagrid data class and whenever I edit that values in datagrid, the class values remain the same as they were brought from database. How could I update them when they are being changed?

```
List<DataClients> myDataItems = new List<DataClients>();
public class DataClients
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Company { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I try to access my datagrid data class in this way. But after editing cell. The selected item columns will still show an old value.

```
private void ClientSave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DataClients selectedClient = (DataClients)clientList.SelectedItem;
    selectedClient.Company;
    selectedClient.Name;
    selectedClient.Id;
}
```

Comment: How do you bind the property? Plus, auto property will not change the value on the View.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` so that your view get the change notifications.

```
ObservableCollection<DataClients> _myDataItems = new ObservableCollection<DataClients>();
```